# ImportError when testing a local Azure Function (Python)?

Tags: python, azure, azure-functions

When I try to run a Python function locally using the Debug tool in VS Code I get an ImportError on one of my dependencies (probably not relevant as to which one it is, but it's pyodbc).

The dependency is listed in my `requirements.txt` file and the whole thing works properly when deployed and run in the cloud.

So, the question is straight forward: how do I test a local Python function that has dependencies by making sure those are properly imported?

**Adding more information:**

When launching the debugger, a pip install is run on the .venv that's in the root of the Azure Functions project. According to my debugger output, the file exists:

`Requirement already satisfied: pyodbc in ./.venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages (from -r requirements.txt (line 7)) (4.0.30)`

The logs are as follows:

```
[6/3/20 7:30:48 PM] Job host started
Hosting environment: Development
Content root path: /Users/my_user/Code/my_directory/azureFunctions
Now listening on: http://0.0.0.0:7071
Application started. Press Ctrl+C to shut down.

Http Functions:

        bhimodelv2: [GET,POST] http://localhost:7071/api/bhimodelv2

[6/3/20 7:30:53 PM] Host lock lease acquired by instance ID '000000000000000000000000391A9F18'.
[6/3/20 7:30:53 PM]  INFO: Starting Azure Functions Python Worker.
[6/3/20 7:30:53 PM]  INFO: Worker ID: e14f3a90-8abd-43f5-8148-90d9d3d98fe3, Request ID: 45d82e44-b75b-40c2-bc94-2afe387d401a, Host Address: 127.0.0.1:63322
[6/3/20 7:30:53 PM]  INFO: Successfully opened gRPC channel to 127.0.0.1:63322
[6/3/20 7:30:53 PM]  INFO: Received WorkerInitRequest, request ID 45d82e44-b75b-40c2-bc94-2afe387d401a
[6/3/20 7:30:53 PM]  INFO: Received FunctionLoadRequest, request ID: 45d82e44-b75b-40c2-bc94-2afe387d401a, function ID: 4cf1e7c7-82ea-4921-aee1-e521bd6c37a1
[6/3/20 7:30:53 PM] Worker failed to function id 4cf1e7c7-82ea-4921-aee1-e521bd6c37a1.
[6/3/20 7:30:53 PM] Result: Failure
[6/3/20 7:30:53 PM] Exception: ImportError: dlopen(/Users/my_user/Code/my_directory/azureFunctions/.venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pyodbc.cpython-37m-darwin.so, 2): Library not loaded: /usr/local/opt/unixodbc/lib/libodbc.2.dylib
[6/3/20 7:30:53 PM]   Referenced from: /Users/my_user/Code/my_directory/azureFunctions/.venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pyodbc.cpython-37m-darwin.so
[6/3/20 7:30:53 PM]   Reason: image not found
[6/3/20 7:30:53 PM] Stack:   File "/Users/my_user/.nvm/versions/node/v10.16.3/lib/node_modules/azure-functions-core-tools/bin/workers/python/3.7/OSX/X64/azure_functions_worker/dispatcher.py", line 243, in _handle__function_load_request
[6/3/20 7:30:53 PM]     func_request.metadata.entry_point)
[6/3/20 7:30:53 PM]   File "/Users/my_user/.nvm/versions/node/v10.16.3/lib/node_modules/azure-functions-core-tools/bin/workers/python/3.7/OSX/X64/azure_functions_worker/loader.py", line 66, in load_function
[6/3/20 7:30:53 PM]     mod = importlib.import_module(fullmodname)
[6/3/20 7:30:53 PM]   File "/usr/local/Cellar/python/3.7.6_1/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/importlib/__init__.py", line 127, in import_module
[6/3/20 7:30:53 PM]     return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
[6/3/20 7:30:53 PM]   File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1006, in _gcd_import
[6/3/20 7:30:53 PM]   File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 983, in _find_and_load
[6/3/20 7:30:53 PM]   File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 953, in _find_and_load_unlocked
[6/3/20 7:30:53 PM]   File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 219, in _call_with_frames_removed
[6/3/20 7:30:53 PM]   File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1006, in _gcd_import
[6/3/20 7:30:53 PM]   File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 983, in _find_and_load
[6/3/20 7:30:53 PM]   File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 967, in _find_and_load_unlocked
[6/3/20 7:30:53 PM]   File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 677, in _load_unlocked
[6/3/20 7:30:53 PM]   File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 728, in exec_module
[6/3/20 7:30:53 PM]   File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 219, in _call_with_frames_removed
[6/3/20 7:30:53 PM]   File "/Users/my_user/Code/my_directory/azureFunctions/bhimodelv2/__init__.py", line 3, in <module>
[6/3/20 7:30:53 PM]     import pyodbc
```

So, the import error occurs AFTER it acknowledges that the file is present in the virtual environment following a successful pip install.

Answer (score 0):

Well, I was wrong - the specific module WAS relevant. `pyodbc` requires you to `brew install unixodbc` when running locally. You won't notice any issues when you deploy your function to Azure because Azure already has those drivers installed.

Here's [where I found that information](https://github.com/mkleehammer/pyodbc/issues/87)